# Java: String.split по URL

Tags: java, split

Всем привет,

есть:

```
String text = "some html with many links like http://mail.ru test"
```

Мне нужно сплитнуть весь текст на куски между определенными ссылками, но когда я делаю

```
text.split("http://mail.ru")
text.split("http://mail\\.ru")
text.split("[http://mail.ru]")
text.split(Pattern.quote("http://mail.ru"))
```

я не получаю разрезание строки по "http://mail.ru".

Как этого можно добиться?

Примечание: StringUtils не вариант, хочется стандартным split сделать

Comment: https://ideone.com/VCA6kM - всё работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://ideone.com/VCA6kM

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Ideone {
  public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
    String text = "some html with many links like http://mail.ru test";
    String[] res = text.split("http://mail\\.ru");

    for (String s : res) {
      System.out.println(s);
    }
  }
}
```

```
some html with many links like 
 test
```

Comment: Да, мой фейл, все и так работает ))